# Load multiple pages with Htmlagilitypack - C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I've scraped a website with HTMLAgilityPack in C#, and I'm trying to open all link inside it and scrape them with same method. 
But when I try to call this method bottom, page is downloaded from library as I have AdBlock active. In fact, I can't find any tables and HTML code downloaded says "ADblock detected".
This is strange because I've filter oddsmath website on my Google Chrome and I can download the master page withouth any problem. Anyone has faced with this problem?

This is the function and the "Console.WriteLine" is just for testing and see full HTML code.

```
   public void GetMatchesDetails()
    {
        List<String> matchDetails = new List<string>();
        foreach (Oddsmath om in oddsmathGoodMatches)
        {
            matchDetails.Add("http://www.oddsmath.com" + om.matchUrl);
        }
        foreach (String om in matchDetails)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(om);

            foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("html"))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Found: " + table.OuterHtml);
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("tr"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("row");
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("cell: " + cell.InnerText);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**EDIT**
Going little deeper, I've noticed that maybe is not a problem of my application or something related to Adblock, but seems connected to website i'm trying to scrape... In fact, if you see a page like this: oddsmath.com/football/international/afc-champions-league-1053/… you can see that content are correctly loaded in browser, but tables are empty inside source code. Why? It's Javascript that prevents loading of page?

Comment: 1. Don't use HAP, use AngleSharp - it's newer and better. 2. Look into setting the user-agent.

Comment: 1) Anglesharp doesn't seems very used compared to HAP, so less support on the web. 2)Do you know how to configure user-agent to have multiple call? Why oddsmath website says that I have adblock installed when I made two or more call with my application (but no when I open two or more tab on my browser)?

Comment: Going little deeper, I've noticed that maybe is not a problem of my application or something related to Adblock, but seems connected to website i'm trying to scrape... In fact, if you see a page like this: http://www.oddsmath.com/football/international/afc-champions-league-1053/2019-04-23/daegu-fc-vs-sanfrecce-hiroshima-2856256/ you can see that content are correctly loaded in browser, but tables are empty inside source code..

Answer (score 1):

First: Use whatever you are most comfortable with HAP vs AngleSharp unless time is really a factor in your application. And in this case it is not.

Second: Use a Web Debugger like Fiddler or Charles to understand what it is that you are actually getting from the when you make a request. Since you are not actually getting any html created with javascript or api calls. You only get the page source. Which is why the tables are empty. They are generated with either javascript.

For instance. I just used a web debugger to see that the site makes an api call to:

```
http://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/dropping-odds.json/?sport_type=soccer&provider_id=7&cat_id=0&interval=60&sortBy=1&limit=30&language=en
```

Then javascript will use this json object to create the rest of page.

And this returns a nice json object that is easier to navigate than with eithr HAP or AngleSharp. I recommend using NewtonSoft JSON.

If you are adamant on using HtmlAgilityPack then you need to combine it with Selenium. Because then you can wait until the page is fully loaded before parsing the HTML.

**[Edit]**
Further digging:

Api-request to get all the leagues and their ids:

```
http://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/menu-leagues.json/?language=en
```

Api-request for just the asian champions league:

```
http://www.oddsmath.com/api/v1/events-by-league.json/?language=en&country_code=GB&league_id=1053
```

## Other solution with Selenium with Firefox driver.

Eventhough I highly recommend that you use API and NewtonSoft-JSON to your solution I will provide how it can be done with Selenium.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Threading;

namespace SeleniumHap {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            string url = "http://www.oddsmath.com/football/sweden/division-1-1195/2019-04-26/if-sylvia-vs-nykopings-bis-2858046/";
            //string url = "http://www.oddsmath.com/";

            FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            //options.AddArguments("--headless");
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            while (true) {
                doc.LoadHtml(driver.PageSource);
                HtmlNode n = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='table-odds-cat-0']//*[self::th or self::td]");
                if (n != null) {
                    n = n.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@class='live-odds-loading']");
                    if (n == null) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Exited loop. Meaning the page is done loading since we could get a td. A Crude method but it works");

            HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");

            foreach(HtmlNode table in tables) {
                Console.WriteLine(table.GetAttributeValue("id", "No id"));
                HtmlNodeCollection tableContent = table.SelectNodes(".//*[self::th or self::td]");
                foreach(HtmlNode n in tableContent) {
                    Console.WriteLine(n.InnerHtml);
                }
                break;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I use Firefox as my driver instead of chrome. When using either you might have to edit the options where you edit the variable *'BrowserExecutableLocation'* to tell where the browser's executable is. 
As you can see I am using a while loop in a crude way to make sure that the browser fully loads page before continuing on reading html.

Comment: Hi Kent, thank you so much for your reply. In this hours I've tried your second approach, so I'm configured my code to open (in headless mode) webpage with Selenium and give it to HtmlAgilityPack to do my scraping. Anyway, this seems not working well, because page is not always rendered with Selenium. Just to give you an example, if I open this link: http://www.oddsmath.com/football/argentina/primera-b-metropolitana-2736/2019-04-22/uai-urquiza-vs-ca-san-telmo-2852265/  with my browser I can do CTRL+S and see full code on saved page, but if I do the same with Selenium this don't work

Comment: In the gym right now. I will refer to one of my earlier answers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47497150/1940851 until I am home again.

Comment: Ok thanks. Tomorrow I will read your article from my pc (I’m on phone now). Do you think you are able with your method (selenium+Htmlagilitypack) to scrape for example main table from site like:www.diretta.it? 
Same problem here: ajax prevents inspect and download of full html code.

Comment: So, few steps: I can save a page rendered with chromedriver and selenium using CTRL+S combination comes from windows form (can't use version comes from Selenium, cause this tools can't work with windows dialog). Problem is: how can I save html code behind page starting selenium chrome driver in headless mode?

Comment: Another hard thing: site like https://www.diretta.it/ hides div in html code that aren't showed in page on browser. This means that if you want to have a complete situation of all football matches, you need to manually show every match and ONLY after save the page

Comment: Kent Kostelac, any news from your side? thank you so much

Comment: At work currently. Am kinda swamped lately. Probably wont have some samples ready before tomorrow. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: NP Kent! Thank you so much for your availability!

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how you Selenium can be used to wait until the page is fully loaded before reading it into a HtmlDocument.

Comment: Thank you Kent. This is really similar to what I've done with Chrome driver (if you want I can share with you something on github). Only two doubts: 1) do you think it's possible to make it work in headless mode? 2) How this can works in site like "diretta.it" that not shows some elements until you click on it? Must I simulate a click on every element of interest?